# setInterval Overlapping DOM changes

Tags: javascript

I'm using `setInterval` to iterate through some images on a page and hide/show the next in a list after x seconds have passed. Every 30 seconds, I make a `GET` request to check for new images from my server. Because the `http` request takes about a second, setInterval begins executing the next iteration of my code which causes things to get a little screwy. What would be the best way to fix this issue? Here is a sample of my code:

```
function play(){
    if(count == 30){
        sync();
        //while sync is running (because it takes so long) the play function is called again before the sync operation finishes. 
    }
    //iterate through the photos hiding and showing them each second. 
}

function sync(){
   //http request that takes about a second to complete and updates images on the page.
}
window.setInterval(function(){
    play();
    currentSeconds++;
    count++;
},1000);
```

Comment: Wrap your http request in a promise, and on resolve you can know you have the images and continue your desired behaviour. I don't know why you need an interval at all to be honest, just call call play on resolve eg `sync().then(() => play());`

Comment: @Asthmatic The reason I am using `setInterval` is because ever second, I check to see (in `play()`) if there is an image that needs to be updated since each of my images have a variable display time.

Comment: I understand. How about you only allow sync to be called again once the previous one has completed, in a similar way. On sync start, set a boolean `SYNCING` to true, then on resolve set it to false. In play, `if (count >= 30 && !SYNCING) sync()`

Comment: @Asthmatic In `play()`, I have an array of images. Each image is assigned a integer as a display time value. If an image has a display time of 4, then on the 4th iteration of set interval, that image will be hidden and the next image shown until its display time expires. While that is going on in `play` I am checking to see if there are any new images available. During this check (http request), the next iteration of `setInterval` executes prematurely causing the wrong images to update on the DOM.

Comment: @Asthmatic I suppose that would probably work.

Comment: maybe switch to a self calling setTimeout. So you only call once you finish an iteration?

Comment: Buffer the response: after the 30s interval, you use the response that was there 30s before, and request the data for the next 30s. This way you have at least 30s to get the response from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```js
function play(){
    if(count == 30){
        sync().then(() => setTimeout(play, 1000));
    } else {
      setTimeout(play, 1000);    
    }
    currentSeconds++;
    count++;      
}

function sync(){ 
    // Use a promise here.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
        }, 3000);
    })
   //http request that takes about a second to complete and updates images on the page.
}

play();
```

OR , use a flag and simply return if sync is busy.

```js
var syncActive = false;
var currentSeconds = 0;
var count = 0;

function play(){
    console.log('trying to play');
    if(syncActive) return false;
    if(count == 30){
        sync(); 
        count = 0;
        
    }
    console.log(`could play - count: ${count}`);
    return true;
}

function sync(){
  syncActive = true;
  console.log('syncing');
 
  // DO LONG TASK
  sleep(5000).then(() => {
    // Note this code is in here to siumlate the long run. 
    console.log('completed sync');
    syncActive = false;  
  });
  

}

window.setInterval(function(){
    if(play()) {
      console.log('increase counts');
      currentSeconds++;
      count++;
    }
},100); //<-- reduced to 100 for demo. 


// DUMMY CODE - Just for demo.

const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
};
```